# Problems using cp -r command

Tags: linux, cp, brace-expansion

I have a series of data with format data*.csv where the first data is data658000.csv and last data is data2040000.csv. The data is every 2000 counts.

I want to filter the data every 90000 counts so I used the command;

```
cp -r /home/data*{658000..2048000..90000}.csv .
```

I expect to get 16 data points;

```
data658000.csv
data748000.csv
data838000.csv
data928000.csv
data1018000.csv
data1108000.csv
data1198000.csv
data1288000.csv
data1378000.csv
data1468000.csv
data1558000.csv
data1648000.csv
data1738000.csv
data1828000.csv
data1918000.csv
data2008000.csv
```

But I am getting 20 data points;

```
data658000.csv
data748000.csv
data838000.csv
data928000.csv
data1018000.csv
data1108000.csv
data1198000.csv
data1288000.csv
data1378000.csv
data1468000.csv
data1558000.csv
data1648000.csv
data1658000.csv
data1738000.csv
data1748000.csv
data1828000.csv
data1838000.csv
data1918000.csv
data1928000.csv
data2008000.csv
```

I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't think that "data1658000.csv" would match "data*658000.csv"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `*` from `data*{658000..2048000..90000}.csv`.

With the `*`, a number that is a suffix of another number would be matched, such as `658000` in `data1658000.csv`.

Since you are copying *files*, you additionally don't need to use `-r` with `cp`.